# JSON Formatting to show last item select from multi selection choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm trying to create a new field that displays the last item select from another Multi selection Choice field. We currently use a choice for Portfolio Years which show as a string of values selected.

Multi Value lookup has a length property to work with but I want to just use the last value of the Choices selected. I don't see a properties or functions hyperlink in the learning center for JSON Formatting.

If I could do a simple split and use the last item in the array.

i.e "2022, 2023,2024" Show just 2024 in the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint JSON column formatting like below for your new column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=substring(join([$PortfolioYears],'||'),lastIndexOf(join([$PortfolioYears],'||'),'||')+2,indexOf(join([$PortfolioYears],'||') + '^', '^'))"
}
```

Where `PortfolioYears` is the name of your multiple selection choice column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

In case if only one year is selected, below JSON should work:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(length([$PortfolioYears])==1,[$PortfolioYears],substring(join([$PortfolioYears],'||'),lastIndexOf(join([$PortfolioYears],'||'),'||')+2,indexOf(join([$PortfolioYears],'||') + '^', '^')))"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That mostly worked. Some came back with 3 digits but a good starting point. I'll have to review the data to see why. It looks like the JSON pretty much follows most javascript functions?

Comment: Can you edit your original question and screenshot of list view where results are coming back with 3 digits? Also, are you using the above JSON as is or you made any changes to it?

Comment: Ahh yes, Seems like it happens when only one choice is selected. How to add image?

Comment: And yes, using your code verbatim

Comment: Check the updated answer and JSON. Let me know if it works for you or if you face any issue.