# SPO JSON - Copy Multiple People Field Emails as Text in New Text Field Commas Separated

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Based on this great [solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309897/json-formatting-to-show-last-item-select-from-multi-selection-choice-field), I am looking for JSON column formatting to copy a multi-person field (people picker), displayed as email

1. into a text field
2. displayed as raw text email format
3. comma separated, and
4. no hyperlink.

**Example**:

People Picker/Email Display: Mary.smith@abcdef.com; John.johnson@xyz.com

Copy to Single Line Text Field: Mary.smith@abcdef.com,John.johnson@xyz.com

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for editing to make this clearer, Ganesh.

Comment: You're welcome! Check solution given below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharePoint column formatting JSON like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join([$PersonColumn.email], ', ')"
}
```

Where `PersonColumn` is internal name of your SharePoint list multiple selection people picker column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This is great. It displays on the aspx page but I'm curious why the new column's text does not export to Excel. Any idea?

Comment: SharePoint JSON formatting only customizes the display of columns/views. It does not actually "store/save" the values in column. If you want to store/save the emails in column, you can try using Power automate flow to update email column values on item creation/update.

Comment: You can update column values using JSON as well but issue is you have to manually click the JSON button to update column values. Column values cannot be automatically updated using JSON formatting - This is a known behavior of SharePoint JSON formatting.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome!